# Django Haystack with elasticsearch providing no results

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

DISCLAIMER: DON'T FEEL THE NEED TO SORT THROUGH ALL THIS CODE BELOW, I JUST HAVE IT HERE TO PROVIDE ALL THE RELEVANT INFORMATION TO THE PROBLEM JUST INCASE

I am making a web app with django and I want to implement a working search bar. After doing some research it seems like haystack with elasticsearch is a popular option. I followed some tutorials, and the one that has gotten me the farthest is this:

http://nanvel.name/2013/07/django-haystack-example

I followed the tutorial the whole way through and got every thing hooked up to my database and models and all that, but when I type something in to the search bar it doesnt give any results, even if the input is a direct match to what's in the database. Here is my code for trying to implement all this.

Model:

```
class GameCard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    console = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    coverArt = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Additions to settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'gamelobby.apps.GamelobbyConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'haystack',
]

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

Addition to views.py

```
def GameCards(request):
    form = GameCardSearchForm(request.GET)
    GameCards = form.search()
    return render_to_response('search/search.html', {'GameCards': GameCards})
```

GameCar_text.txt file:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.coverArt }}
```

Search_indexes.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from haystack import indexes

from .models import GameCard


class GameCardIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    coverArt = indexes.CharField(model_attr='coverArt')

    def get_model(self):
        return GameCard

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now())
```

search.html:

```
{% extends 'gamelobby/home.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form type="get" action=".">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

{% for GameCard in GameCards %}
<h1>{{ GameCard.title }}</h1>
<p>
    {{ GameCard.coverArt }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py:

```
class GameCardSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()
```

I'm pretty sure I have every base covered here, I cant figure out why no results are being shown on the html page. And btw of course I have the search.html hooked up to the main other html file with the block tags I just thought it would take up too much space to include all that html from that file, plus I did not believe it is relevant to the problem. Anyways it would be great if anyone had any tips or solutions and please dont feel the need to go through all this code I just felt it would be right to give on the information possible. Thanks!

Comment: hey this should help: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/debugging.html

Comment: Just a suggestion, not familiar with haystack,  if this is backed by ES it might be worth doing the query directly to ES through curl / browser, just to check that ES is working.

Comment: Have you built the index after defining it? `python manage.py rebuild_index`?